# Symfony/doctrine slip element in textarea before persist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi i'm new in symfony2 and i want to make one thing

I have in my view a textarea, and in this textarea i want to put somme name, one per line like:

```
john
frank
...
```

and i want to persist each one in database...

I have in the controller:

```
    $formBuilderMultiple = $this->container
        ->get('form.factory')
        ->createNamedBuilder('formMultiple', 'form', NULL)
        ->add('users', 'textarea')
        ->add('add', 'submit');

    $formMultiple = $formBuilderMultiple->getForm();


    if ($formMultiple->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

       // what to write here??


    }
```

I want to make a thing like :

```
foreach(explode("\n", $formMultiple->users) as $line) {
     var_dump($line);
}
```

How can I do?

Thank's :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two best solutions for this kind of job will be:

1) Add an event listener on the `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT` event to the field `users`, where you will take the submitted value and process it as you need it and resubmit it in the new form. More: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

2) Use a data transformer: you can create a data transformer that will transform strings into arrays and also arrays into strings by imploding/exploding based on a given delimiter. More: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

But you can also do all this stuff into your controller, which is not recommended:

```
$submittedFormData = $formMultiple->getData();
foreach(explode("\n", $submittedFormData['users']) as $user) {
    var_dump($user);
}
```